# Disable SNI on Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, https, sni

I've a Windows Server 2016 installed with Apache 2.4.37

In the Apache server, I've setup multiple virtual host like:

- **abc**.host.com
- **def**.host.com
- **ghi**.host.com

All this virtual host share the same IP address and certificate in wildcard ***.host.com**

We're enchance the website to link to a 3rd party service for online transaction now. But we face an error when handshake with the 3rd party service. We suspect it's SNI issue because 3rd party service document state that **No SNI**.

My questions are:

1. Base on my Apache server, do it need SNI? I'm not familiar to server setting and SNI, what I understand from Internet is that SNI is for multiple domain share the same IP with different certificate. But my scenario is same domain name, only different in sub domain, and they are all share the same certificate. Is this still involve SNI?
2. How can I disable SNI in server.
3. When I search Internet, I found one website mention about SNI on firewall. Is it mean firewall may also have set SNI? instead of Apache server.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does the third party service contact you, or do you contact the third party service?

Comment: We call the 3rd party service, when the process complete, they will redirect back to our web site. The error happened when they redirect back to our web site.